# The DrawerNavigator function name is deprecated, please use createDrawerNavigator instead

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i have used createDrawerNavigator but its not working
my code is

//App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './SettingsScreen';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hey</Text>
        <MyApp/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const MyApp=createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:HomeScreen
  },
  Settings:{
    screen :SettingsScreen
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});




//HomeScreen.js

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text>Hey There</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
  }
  export default HomeScreen;

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
},
  });

//SettingScreen.js

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text>Hey There</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
  }
  export default SettingsScreen;

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
},
  });
```

please anyone knows how to create drawerlayout in react-native explain it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `alignItems: 'center'` of your **HomeScreen** style should do the job.